# Jar File is running in my computer but not Running in another computer

Tags: java, jar

I created a jar file in my laptop and it runs fine in my computer without trouble but when i use the same in my friend's laptop it shows and exception and the file does not run. But it's still good with my laptop. What's the reason?

**name of jar =*BlueServer.jar*
it has only one class.

classname=*Server.java* 
one external library is used name=*Bluecove.jar* which is used for accessing bluetooth from java.
Ide used=Eclipse
used Eclipse for creating jar,already checked the option "Pacakage required libraries into generated jar"**

**This Error came while i try to run that same jar in another computer....**

java -jar BlueServer.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Server : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

```
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
```

Comment: Then i have to check for each user of my jar have higher jdk or lower. Is there any general method so that i will not bother about the version of jdk of the user of that jar

Comment: @ShekharKumar Not in general, but usually if you set the compiler to java 5 (aka 1.5) you should not have this problem anymore nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the version of the used JRE. See [this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0).
Try

```
java --version
```

on both machines.

Comment: Use java -version for checking the versions.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates, that your file is not executable with the installed JRE version.

See [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) for more info about that.

Comment: Then i have to check  for each user of my jar have higher jdk or lower.
Is there any general method so that i will not bother about the version of jdk of the user of that jar

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime. Make sure the jdk version installed in your laptop is equal or higher than your friend's.

Comment: Then how i know for each client have higher jdk or lower..

Comment: Is there any general method so that i will not bother about the version of jdk of the user of that jar